# embed youtube on mobile website thumb display

Tags: html, youtube, embed, mobile-website

When I embed a youtube video in my mobile website with following code:

```
<iframe width="60" height="40" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/JW5meKfy3fY?controls=0&showinfo=0&showsearch=0&modestbranding=1"></iframe>
```

the thumbs in the webview on my iPhone shows this:
[image]

after clicking it the video starts playing as it should do,
when closing the movie the thumbs are shown like this:
[image]

is there any way to show the thumb like the 2nd image when the page is loaded?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

The second icon is the iPhones default media play button and nothing to do with the YouTube player (I think). You could try embedding the YouTube player with JavaScript and using the API to theme and style the player: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the thumb image from youtube.

http://img.youtube.com/vi/JW5meKfy3fY/1.jpg

(I am looking the same kind of  url of the thumb image for screenr)